# how to divide n numbers among N processors using open mp

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing, openmp

I was a given a task to perform CREW sort in parallel programming. As the first step of this, I have an array of size n and N processors, I need to divide these elements among N processors and sort each part sequentially and merge them back , how can I do this in openmp. I am new to using openmp ,so any resources to solve this problem will be helpful.

Comment: https://www.openmp.org//wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf Is a very good resource to get the basics. But don't just read everything. Chapters 2, 4 and 5 are probably not useful as a beginner. There is also a version with openmp 5 here https://www.openmp.org/specifications/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote from the back of my head. It might not be optimal and is not tested. But it should give you a direction how to handle such a problem.

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openmp.h>

ptrdiff_t min(ptrdiff_t a, ptrdiff_t b) {
  return ((a > b) ? b : a);
}

void inplace_sequential_sort(double *data, ptrdiff_t n) { /* ... */ }

void inplace_merge(double *data, ptrdiff_t n1, ptrdiff_t n2) { /* ... */ }

void inplace_parallel_sort(double *data, ptrdiff_t n) {
  if (n < 2) 
    return;

  /* allocate memory for helper array */
  int const max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
  ptrdiff_t *my_n = calloc(max_threads, sizeof(*my_n));
  if (!my_n) { /* ... */ }

  #pragma omp parallel default(none) \
    shared(n, data, my_n)
  {
    /* get thread ID and actual number of threads */
    int const tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int const N = omp_get_num_threads();

    /* distribute data among threads */
    ptrdiff_t const max_elem_per_thread = ((n + N - 1) / N);
    ptrdiff_t const my_begin = min(tid * max_elem_per_thread, n);
    my_n[tid] = min(n - begin, max_elem_per_thread);

    if (my_n[tid] > 1)
      inplace_squential_sort(data + my_begin, my_n[tid]);

    /* merge sorted data sections (parallel reduction algorithm) */
    for (ptrdiff_t stride = 1; stride < N; stride *= 2 ) {
      #pragma omp barrier
      if (ti % (2 * stride) == 0 && my_begin + my_n[tid] != n) {
        inplace_merge(data + my_begin, my_n[tid], my_n[tid + stride]);
        my_n[tid] += my_n[tid + stride];
      }
    }
  } /* end of parallel region */

  free(my_n); 
}
```

I assumed that you want a C solution (not C++ or Fortran) and sort the data inplace. This is a very basic solution. OpenMP can do much more (e.g. tasking). The functions inplace_sequantial_sort() and inplace_merge() have to be provided.